# How we create dump file of daily inserted, updated and deleted records in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql

We are creating dump file of multiple database at every one hour but the issue is storage and time of restoration. We have multiple location create dump file and using vpn to get the file. file become large day by day. Please suggest me any solution

Comment: Don't use dump files, use WAL archiving and point in time recovery. There are tools that will automate all that for you, e.g. [pgbackrest](https://pgbackrest.org/) or [barman](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/barman/)

Comment: If you create a dump regularly, why is the file getting bigger and bigger? Is the database size increasing as well?

Comment: Yes, database size are increasing day to day. We have various database at various location and we are creating dump file of each location and at last we collect all data at a central place then we drop previous day data and restore these new one. This take so much time . we are now using slony-I for this but some time those database have duplicate data is not restored

Comment: And I dont know how to use pgbackrest